# Problem with \usepackage{standalone} in standalone file in new TeX Live distribution

Tags: standalone

I have ONE standard file that I use in ALL my files including the standalone files.
This method was working fine until today, when I updated my texlive distribution using `sudo /usr/texbin/tlmgr update --all` command. Once this completed, I got the following error `Extra \fi`. I found that the reason was that the standalone files were including the standalone package.

I know I can easily workaround this using `\ifdefined\standalone`, so am posting this here in case others update and have the same problem.  Here is the smallest file that reproduces this problem.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% Now include my standard packages, which also includes:
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
foobar
\end{document}
```

Also the NEW version of standalone package reports: `standalone.cfg 2010/02/28 v0.4` where as the older one reported `standalone.cfg 2010/03/27 v0.3a`, which is dated AFTER the v0.4 version.

I suspect that this is just a typo in the new version and should have probably been 2011.

**Update:** Ok, now I think that this is problem as I am not able to get a basic main file which includes a standalone file to work without getting the above error. Here is the standalone file (similar to the standalone doc) called `StandaloneProblem.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw   (0 ,0)  circle  (2) node    [midway]    {Example};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the main file:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{standalone} % Load all packages needed for all sub−files :
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} 
        \input{StandaloneProblem} \caption{A subfile}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the `Extra \fi` error as mentioned above.

Comment: Please always report bugs in packages directly to the package author(s) using the email address mentioned in the package manual. Ok, I'm the author of this package so you don't need to do this again. But as a bug report it is kind of off-topic here.

Comment: I fixed this now and uploaded the fix as v0.4a. My apologies for that. Some experimental code was accidentally included into the release and there was a `\iffalse` missing. The new version will be available on CTAN shortly and then can be updated using TeXLive after an additional short while. It is also available from the [package website](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/standalone/browser/releases/v0.4a).

Comment: @Peter. I'm minded to close this as 'too localised' as it relates to a specific bug that is now apparently fixed. However, first I'd like to know that the fix sorts the issue out for you: does it?

Comment: @Joseph: I removed the trailing `\fi` which caused the error and tested it with the provided files.

Comment: @Martin. I understood that :-) Ages ago there was another case where a bug report led to a package author saying 'this is fixed'. At the time, the feeling was that we should wait for 'independent' confirmation, which broadly means that the OP has to agree on closing the question.

Comment: Yep, this has indeed been fixed, and things are working great, so can be closed. Thanks everyone involved.